# PostgreSQL client (psql) cannot connect after starting service with pgenv or pg_ctl

Tags: postgresql

I'm able to start the service with pgenv and pg_ctl but cannot connect with psql.  The following error shows:

```
$ psql -l
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I checked the path of the mentioned socket but it does not exist as psql reports.

If I use **pg_ctl status**, the following is returned:

```
$ pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 2127388)
/home/postgres/Repositories/github.com/theory/pgenv/pgsql-15.2/bin/postgres
```

I checked the server.log file and it says that is listening on a different socket.  Please see the following:

```
$ file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: socket
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

All there was to do was to create the directory /run/postgresql and assign the right permissions to that same directory.  Ownership must belong to the system user account (e.g. postgres) that is executing postgresql.